# Unable to start spring boot after adding @EnableSwagger2 in TestApplication

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui

Although I rebuilt the project and added `@EnableSwagger2`, it is still the case. Is this a problem with `swagger-ui`? But the console output is a problem with the `documentationPluginsBootstrapper` of spring boot

### TestApplication.java

```java
package com.example.test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@EnableSwagger2
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

### pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.14</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Test</name>
    <description>Test</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

### console

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-Dmanagement.endpoints.jmx.exposure.include=*" -javaagent:C:\Users\SurKaa\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\231.9161.38\lib\idea_rt.jar=3612:C:\Users\SurKaa\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\231.9161.38\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\jre\lib\rt.jar;E:\SpringBoot\Me\Test\target\classes;E:\Others\MavenRepository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.7.14\spring-boot-starter-web-2.7.14.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.7.14\spring-boot-starter-2.7.14.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.7.14\spring-boot-2.7.14.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.7.14\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.14.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.7.14\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.7.14.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.12\logback-classic-1.2.12.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.12\logback-core-1.2.12.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.17.2\log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.2.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.17.2\log4j-api-2.17.2.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.36\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.36.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.30\snakeyaml-1.30.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.7.14\spring-boot-starter-json-2.7.14.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.13.5\jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.13.5\jackson-core-2.13.5.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.13.5\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.5.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.13.5\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.5.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.13.5\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.5.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.7.14\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.7.14.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.78\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.78\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.78.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.78\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.78.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.29\spring-web-5.3.29.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.29\spring-beans-5.3.29.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.29\spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.29\spring-aop-5.3.29.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.29\spring-context-5.3.29.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.29\spring-expression-5.3.29.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\io\springfox\springfox-swagger2\2.9.2\springfox-swagger2-2.9.2.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\io\swagger\swagger-annotations\1.5.20\swagger-annotations-1.5.20.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\io\swagger\swagger-models\1.5.20\swagger-models-1.5.20.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.13.5\jackson-annotations-2.13.5.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\io\springfox\springfox-spi\2.9.2\springfox-spi-2.9.2.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\io\springfox\springfox-core\2.9.2\springfox-core-2.9.2.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\io\springfox\springfox-schema\2.9.2\springfox-schema-2.9.2.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\io\springfox\springfox-swagger-common\2.9.2\springfox-swagger-common-2.9.2.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\io\springfox\springfox-spring-web\2.9.2\springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\com\google\guava\guava\20.0\guava-20.0.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.36\slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\org\springframework\plugin\spring-plugin-core\1.2.0.RELEASE\spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\org\springframework\plugin\spring-plugin-metadata\1.2.0.RELEASE\spring-plugin-metadata-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\org\mapstruct\mapstruct\1.2.0.Final\mapstruct-1.2.0.Final.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\io\springfox\springfox-swagger-ui\2.9.2\springfox-swagger-ui-2.9.2.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.28\lombok-1.18.28.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.12.23\byte-buddy-1.12.23.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.29\spring-core-5.3.29.jar;E:\Others\MavenRepository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.29\spring-jcl-5.3.29.jar" com.example.test.TestApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v2.7.14)

2023-08-05 21:44:04.042  INFO 19640 --- [           main] com.example.test.TestApplication         : Starting TestApplication using Java 1.8.0_371 on SurKaa-Windows10 with PID 19640 (E:\SpringBoot\Me\Test\target\classes started by SurKaa in E:\SpringBoot\Me\Test)
2023-08-05 21:44:04.045  INFO 19640 --- [           main] com.example.test.TestApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-08-05 21:44:04.829  INFO 19640 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-08-05 21:44:04.835  INFO 19640 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-08-05 21:44:04.835  INFO 19640 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.78]
2023-08-05 21:44:04.949  INFO 19640 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-08-05 21:44:04.949  INFO 19640 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 862 ms
2023-08-05 21:44:05.174  INFO 19640 --- [           main] pertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/v2/api-docs] onto method [springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller#getDocumentation(String, HttpServletRequest)]
2023-08-05 21:44:05.306  INFO 19640 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-08-05 21:44:05.307  INFO 19640 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Context refreshed
2023-08-05 21:44:05.320  INFO 19640 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)
2023-08-05 21:44:05.323  WARN 19640 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
2023-08-05 21:44:05.628  INFO 19640 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-08-05 21:44:05.637  INFO 19640 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-08-05 21:44:05.666 ERROR 19640 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:357) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:156) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:124) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:938) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) [spring-boot-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) [spring-boot-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) [spring-boot-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) [spring-boot-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at com.example.test.TestApplication.main(TestApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.Orderings$8.compare(Orderings.java:112) ~[springfox-spi-2.9.2.jar:null]
    at springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.Orderings$8.compare(Orderings.java:109) ~[springfox-spi-2.9.2.jar:null]
    at com.google.common.collect.ComparatorOrdering.compare(ComparatorOrdering.java:37) ~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
    at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1438) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at com.google.common.collect.Ordering.sortedCopy(Ordering.java:855) ~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.requestHandlers(WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.java:57) ~[springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar:null]
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper$2.apply(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:138) ~[springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar:null]
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper$2.apply(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:135) ~[springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar:null]
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$7.transform(Iterators.java:750) ~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:47) ~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:47) ~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.MultitransformedIterator.hasNext(MultitransformedIterator.java:52) ~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.MultitransformedIterator.hasNext(MultitransformedIterator.java:50) ~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:249) ~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:209) ~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.FluentIterable.toList(FluentIterable.java:614) ~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.defaultContextBuilder(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:111) ~[springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar:null]
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.buildContext(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:96) ~[springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar:null]
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.start(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:167) ~[springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar:null]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:179) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    ... 14 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

### file tree

```
卷 Workspace 的文件夹 PATH 列表
卷序列号为 D2AD-7F6C
E:\SPRINGBOOT\ME\TEST\SRC
+---main
|   +---java
|   |   \---com
|   |       \---example
|   |           \---test
|   |                   TestApplication.java
|   |
|   \---resources
|       |   application.properties
|       |
|       +---static
|       \---templates
\---test
    \---java
        \---com
            \---example
                \---test
                        TestApplicationTests.java
```

### some details

- `JAVA`: openjdk version "1.8.0_372" OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.372.07.1 (build 1.8.0_372-b07) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.372.07.1 (build 25.372-b07, mixed mode)
- `SpringBoot Version`: 2.7.14
- `Swagger-ui Version`: 2.9.2

I tried `springboot 3` and `swagger-ui 3` before, but the result is still the same as above, and there is still a problem with `documentationPluginsBootstrapper`

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by Spring Fox 3.0.0 not supporting new PathPattern Based Path Matching Strategy for Spring MVC which is now the new default from spring-boot 2.6.0

I recommend you to switch to new one doc API [springdoc-openapi](https://springdoc.org/migrating-from-springfox.html) because springfox (documentationProvider): Springfox is deprecated for removal in version 7.0. 0 of openapi-generator. The project seems to be no longer maintained (last commit is of Oct 14, 2020). It works with Spring Boot 2.5.